# sublime text 2 build system for C programming language

Tags: c, build, system, sublimetext2

I'm learning C language. I'm referring book by Dennis Ritchie & Kernighan. And there fore Just ANSI complaint programs. I've installed ANSI compiler. I just installed Sublime text 2 editor. Could someone give me a build system that would do the following.

1) Compile my source file

2) Display error (in well formatted manner) within sublime on unsuccessful compilation.

3) On successful compilation, Generate binary file with name same as the Source file name within my working directory.

4) Accept Any user input within sublime to calculate Output. (Since i'm a beginner i mostly write programs that would ask the user to input. ex: Program to calculate number of characters in user input name.)

5) Separate selection for Compile & run.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: ST2 doesn't allow user input, i.e. your 4th request.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From menu, choose Build -> New build system ...
and copy-paste this:

**Windows**

*Compile Only:*

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lm", "-Wall"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell":true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

*Compile & Run:*

```
{
    "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["cc","-std=c99" ,"$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lm", "-Wall", "&","start", "${file_base_name}.exe"]
    },
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",
}
```

**Linux**

*Compile Only:*

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}", "-lm", "-Wall"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell":false,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

*Compile & Run:*

```
{
    "linux":
    {
        "cmd": ["cc","-std=c99" ,"$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}", "-lm", "-Wall", ";", "./${file_base_name}"]
    },
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",
}
```

and save this with extension *.sublime-build

ST just is a editor, so you cannot use it as a input stream, you have to use a shell like bash, zsh, ... to do it.

Comment: c633: I'm very thankful to you. It works. Really Appreciate your response. :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be already enough without instructing GCC to link with  math library `-lm`?

Comment: Is there any _sublime_ way to keep the shell open after exec. on windows? I mean, it only avoids writing an extra line in C, but it might be helpful for lazy people like me... Or is it possible to use the buildlog as output?

Answer (score 0):

See the status bar down in sublime text 2 where it says the language or it says 'plain text',
click it and search for 'c' language. to build you just need to save `Ctrl-s` and Build `Ctrl-B` , Easy as cake!. also you could try a C friendly IDE  like Eclipse. http://www.eclipse.org/

Comment: Dr. Astragalo: I need build system for the requirements mentioned above. Existing build system doesn't provide all the features mentioned above. 

The default build system isn't working either. C is seleted and when i build i get "The system cannot find the file specified" Error. 

Compiler installed Location: C:\MingGW\bin
PATH is specified in Environment variables properly.