# How to trigger 2 functions depending on build result?

Tags: sublimetext

I want to setup build system so:

- If build is successful, run my program
- If not, it automatically jump to the first error (i.e. as if I pressed <kbd>F4</kbd> once)

Simplest way I see it is to setup a callback with

```
"command": "next_result"
```

Which would navigate to first error in case build fails.

How could I do it?

I feel it should be something very evident, but cannot find anything in build reference.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your programming language but cf this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670064/sublime-text-2-build-system-for-c-programming-language) to get the configuration for a `C` build (with `gcc`).

Then add a regex in `file_regex`:

```
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$"
```

This should catch and highlight all the warnings/errors produced by `gcc` : `Sublime Text` will automatically jump to the next one when you press <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) for more details.

**[EDIT]** For custom commands, you can edit the User's Key Binding file.
For syntax example, in the Default one you have:

```
{ "keys": ["f4"], "command": "next_result" }
```

where `next_result` is the callback called when you press <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: I capture regex fine. I just don't want to press F4 extra time. Basically I want to setup a sublime callback on build fail.

Comment: If you already have your function, then you just have to edit the key bindings: did you try it ?

Comment: Maybe I poorly specified the question. When I press Ctrl+Enter(my build key) I want to specify 2 callbacks - in case of success, program runs, in case of fail - sublime goes to first found error(as if I pressed F4). I just don't know any way to set a callback on build result.

Comment: Ok, I took the liberty of editing your question then.
I'm also new to Sublime but I think the function we call (like `next_result`) are python function store somewhere : I guess that you can write your own. Maybe have a look [there](https://sublime.wbond.net/) and see how plugins are implemented.